# jQuery sliding animation not working

Tags: jquery, animation

I have three divs stacked on each other but offset so that a part of each div is visible.  When one of the bottom divs is clicked I want the top div to animate out and back into the stack at the bottom, then the div that is clicked will appear at the top.  So far I only have the code for when the middle div is clicked, but I cannot get it to work properly.  What am I doing wrong? (I also realize that the code I wrote is probably terrible, this is the first jQuery code I have written.)

The css is very very simple:

```
    .first {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .second {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .third {
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

The basic html is this:

```
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
```

Here is my code:

```
    $("div.second").click(function () {
        $("div.first").animate({
            left: "-=200px"},
            {duration: "fast",
            complete: function () {
                $("div.first").removeClass("first").addClass("third").animate({left: "+=350px", top: "+=60px"}, "fast");
            }
        });
        $("div.second").animate({
            left: "-=24px", top: "-=30px"},
            {duration: "fast",
            complete: function () {
                $("div.second").removeClass("second").addClass("first");
            }
        });
        $("div.third").animate({
            left: "-=24px", top: "-=30px"},
            {duration: "fast",
            complete: function () {
                $("div.third").removeClass("third").addClass("second");
            }
        });
    });
```

I can get the div.first to move to the side and back. But now I can't get the classes to stay changed.  What keeps happening is the div.second will remove it's class and add .first in the animation, but when the animation is complete, it acts like it still has a class of .second.

Comment: Can you show some markup as well?

Comment: I added the basic html and css that im using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That coding style is very inefficient.

Use something like this, It applies to every div

```
$("div").click(function() {
   var first = $(".first");
   var fleft = first.css("left");
   var ftop = first.css("top");           

   var $this = $(this);
   var tLeft = $this.css('left');
   var tTop = $this.css('top');
   var tClass = $this.attr("class");

   first.animate({
      left: tLeft,
      top: tTop
   }).attr("class", tClass);

   $this.animate({
       top: ftop,
       left: fleft
   }).attr("class", "first");        

});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/pDZ9A/1/)

Comment: I am having a hard time following what this code is doing.  I should mention that my div's have id's that might change how this works.

Comment: @JakeZeitz, I answered as much as i understood. See the update and the demo

Comment: @Starx - You use `$(this)` 4 times. To make it more efficient, you should cache at the beginning with `var $this = $(this);`.

Comment: ah the demo is key.  I am figuring it out slowly hah. thanks.

Comment: I have a new problem now.  If I encase the moveable div's inside a container div I get really weird results.  Is there a way to make the clickable div more specific??

Comment: @JakeZeitz, Show us a demo of what you mean

Comment: actually I managed to fix it.  I changed `$("div")` to `$("div#1, div#2, div#3)`.  Thanks for all your help man.

Comment: @JakeZeitz, Do not give integer value as id to any element. You might use something like `mydiv1` as the name. The problem arises when you are manipulating the div with javascript.

Comment: @Starx, ah I was just trying to simplify it, I don't actually use integers for my code.  Now I am trying to make the divs switch places when you click on an outside button... check out what I have been trying in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/bz6cH/2/ .  I want there to be two classes current and notcurrent so I can have many divs that can be accessed and switched.

Comment: @Starx, you may also want to look at my actual webpage to get a better idea of what I want to happen: http://www.guitarseeker.com/guitars/ right now the code I am using is very inefficient and will make it much more time consuming when adding more panels